# In iOS, how do you get the current line width of a CGContext?

Tags: ios, cgcontext, stroke

There's a call `CGContextSetLineWidth`, but I don't see a corresponding `CGContextGetLineWidth` or even a `CGContextLineWidth`.  How can I get the current width set in the context?  I need to know what this is for my draw routines in a library.

Answer (score 3):

In a newly created context, the line width is always 1. Can you just keep track of the line width manually whenever it is changed within your library by using using a variable?

Comment: Of course *I* can do that, but when building a reusable library that does some drawing, I don't control the line width unless someone passes it in.  That's not too bad but it means since I'm changing the context state, I also have to revert it, and I don't know how expensive the save/restore methods are.  One thing, CGContextRef is just a pointer type for a CGContext structure, but I don't see that structure defined anywhere.  Was hoping Line Width was a member of it, but again, I can't find it in the headers.

Comment: Fair enough. I had a look but I can't find it either. I think you'll either have to save/restore the context as you suggest, or redesign your API so that CGContext is not exposed (allowing you to control how it it manipulated internally and ensure that line width, etc are not altered except via your methods).

Comment: Yeah, can't redesign it considering this is an API for working directly with the CGContext, so that's out.  I'm a little leery about the save/restore state thing because that can get very expensive if people are using several of our drawing calls, especially in the same loop.  Guess I'll just have to tell people when they use it, a) they have to pass in the width, and b) when they do, it will change it for the context.  Stinks, but what can ya do.